# How to redirect another page after send_file from controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm submitting one form and after data saved from controller side, one file generation completed and before redirect want to send_file which through file in browser. Some documents shows that you can't do both `send_file` and redirection from same action, is that right?